# Обращение к полям через super или this в классе-наследнике

Tags: java

Уважаемые пользователи stackoverflow, здравствуйте. Нужен ваш совет.
Есть пример кода. Вопрос: почему я могу обратиться к полю родителя и с помощью this и с помощью super?
Как я сам понимаю: super позволяет обращаться к методам и полям родителя, а this ну вроде бы как к полям этого класса, а раз "этот класс" наследуется от родителя, то и к его полям что ли?

```
    public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    public static class Pet {
        protected String name;

        public Pet() {
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    public static class Cat extends Pet {
        @Override
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = "";
            super.name = "";// на первый взгляд, разницы нет
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все верно, это и есть наследование. В вашем примере класс `Cat` наследует поле `name` и к нему можно обращаться используя `this`. Ключевое слово `super` явно указывает, что вы хотите обратится к полю родительского класса. Дело в том, что в классе `Cat` вы можете объявить поле `name`. Теперь при обращении `this.name` вы будете обращаться к полю класса `Cat`. Если хотите обратиться к полю родительского класса, необходимо использовать `super`: `super.name`

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно в вашем примере разницы действительно никакой нет.

Все зависит от области видимости поля. Вы пометили поле `name` модификатором `protected` именно это делает ее доступной в классе наследнике, и дает вам право обращаться к ней напрямую.

Вам не надо переопределять метод `setName(String)` в объекте `Cat`, он и так доступен из вне так как помечен модификатором `public`. Например так будет работать из-за модификатора `protected`

```
public class Pet {
    protected String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class Cat extends Pet {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println( name ); //здесь будет работать и через this  и через super и без них
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.setName( youCatName );
    }
}
```

а если пометите поле как `private`, то как в прошлом примере обратиться к ней не сможете, но сможете получить ее значение через метод`getName()`,т.к. он у вас имеет модификатор `public`

```
public static class Pet {
    private String name;

    public Pet() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public static class Cat extends Pet {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println( getName() )
    }
}
```